# How to disable zuul decoding encoded slash %2F?

Tags: java, spring-cloud, netflix-eureka, spring-cloud-netflix

I'm using a solution with Spring Cloud Zuul and Eureka. The REST application register itself with Eureka and Zuul provide access to the Service via Eureka Service Discovery.

I had to configure the REST application to accept encoded slash in URL with:

```
System.setProperty("org.apache.tomcat.util.buf.UDecoder.ALLOW_ENCODED_SLASH", "true");
```

To accept encoded dash in the Spring Boot REST application, and:

```
@Bean
public HttpFirewall allowUrlEncodedSlashHttpFirewall() {
    DefaultHttpFirewall firewall = new DefaultHttpFirewall();
    firewall.setAllowUrlEncodedSlash(true);
    return firewall;
}

@Override
public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
    web.httpFirewall(allowUrlEncodedSlashHttpFirewall());
}
```

In `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` for the same purpose. And:

```
@Override
public void configurePathMatch(PathMatchConfigurer configurer) {
    UrlPathHelper urlPathHelper = new UrlPathHelper();
    urlPathHelper.setUrlDecode(false);
    configurer.setUrlPathHelper(urlPathHelper);
}
```

In `WebMvcConfigurer` to skip decoding url encoded characters.

After that, the REST application alone started to answer normally the request with the encoded slash. When I connected the REST application with Zuul, the gateway, the problem happened with slash encoded happens again. I did the same configuration of REST application with Zuul plus the property `decode-url: false` in application.yml and the combination of Zuul and REST application worked again.

When I added the Service Discovery/Service Registration solution with Eureka, the problem begun happen again. I searched a lot, even cloned the [Spring Cloud Netflix Eureka Server 2.1.0.RELEASE](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-netflix/tree/50be967c05ee1925849b93016d2026257975cef2/spring-cloud-netflix-eureka-server) and [Eureka Core 1.9.8](https://github.com/Netflix/eureka/tree/0f960da863adc874c42a0caacd27ca8f50328dbf/eureka-core) but couldn't find any solution.

How to disable the decoding of slash in Eureka encoded in URL?

Comment: Eureka doesn't have anything to do with encoding urls

Comment: @spencergibb thanks so much for your comment. After you give that hint about be a zuul problem, I created four simple projects to simulate my scenario with minimum configuration. And everything worked! But not in my real solution. Then I tried to enable/disable all the configurations to find where was the difference between the simpler scenario and real one (suspected about https, cors, etc... no luck). At the end, the problem was spring boot version 2.1.3.RELEASE in the gateway. After change to version 2.1.4.RELEASE everything works!

Answer (score 1):

The solution is to change Spring Boot version from 2.1.3.RELEASE to 2.1.4.RELEASE in the gateway.